# `\underbrace` disturbs balanced vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, equations

How do I avoid the empty spacing above equation elements between `\left(` and `\right)`?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:abe-kokos}
  \underbrace{5
    \left(
    \underbrace{5
    \left(
      \underbrace{5
      \left(
        \underbrace{5
        \left(
          \underbrace{5
          \left(
            \underbrace{5\cdot n+1}_\text{alle}
          \right)+1}_\text{femte sømand}
        \right)+1}_\text{Nødder til fjerde sømand}
      \right)+1}_\text{Kokosnødder, som tredje sømand tager}
    \right)+1}_\text{Så mange deler den anden sømand -- og giver aben 1}
  \right)+1}_\text{Antal kokosnødder, som den første sømand deler -- og aben får 1}
  =
  5^6n+\sum_{j=0}^{5}5^j
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Nested parantheses with \underbrace creating space above]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,delarray}
\newcommand\myub[2]{\begin{array}[t]({@{}c@{}})\underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}\end{array}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:abe-kokos}
  \myub{5\myub{5\myub{5\myub{5\myub{5\myub{5\cdot n+1}{alle}
          +1}{femte sømand}
        +1}{Nødder til fjerde sømand}
      +1}{Kokosnødder, som tredje sømand tager}
    +1}{Så mange deler den anden sømand -- og giver aben 1}
  +1}{Antal kokosnødder, som den første sømand deler -- og aben får 1}
  =
  5^6n+\sum_{j=0}^{5}5^j
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was not aware of the [delarray](https://ctan.org/pkg/delarray) package -- but now I am!