# Control the width of an underbrace

Tags: underbrace

[image]

I would like to shorten this underbrace so that it terminates directly underneath the vertical bars without extending past them.

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\Underbrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#2}_{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \[\Underbrace{a}{|x+y|}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The underbrace covers the entire width of the object, which includes the space around the vertical bars. You can remove the outer spaces using `\Underbrace{\!|x+y|\!}`. But the use case would change dependent on the input.

Comment: Did you try  $|\Underbrace{a}{x+y}|$?

Comment: @Bernard Clarified the question, sorry.

Comment: @Werner That's perfect, thanks! What do you mean about the use case?

Comment: @simplejack: The spacing correction will depend on what you supply. Take [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/YwJ7E960) as an example. Even with `\!` the `\underbrace` still stretches too wide because of the additional space around the extensible delimeters.

Comment: @Werner I see. Also, it gets messed up when trying to write a product such as $|x||y|$ with an underbrace under each factor.

Comment: @simplejack: Riiight. For that you'll need `$\,\Underbrace{..}{\!|x|\!}\,\,\Underbrace{..}{\!|y|\!}\,$`. Here `\!` is the negative of `\,`. See [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Comment: @Werner Thanks so much!

Comment: The answers in these questions address this problem: [How to prevent an underbrace, with a subscript, from affecting the sizes of delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435697) and [`\underbrace` disturbs balanced vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496902)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of these solutions – the second is similar to  @Werner's suggestion, with the negative thin spaces compensated with thin spaces befor and after the underbrace:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\Underbrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#2}_{#1}}}

\begin{document}

    \[\Underbrace{a}{|x+y|} \neq |\Underbrace{a}{x+y}|\neq\,\Underbrace{a}{\!|x+y|\!}\,\]

\end{document}
```

[image]